# Strange Jquery problem

Tags: jquery, html, animation, cross-browser, jquery-animate

basically i've created a portfolio gallery see this link http://www.michaeldg.com/index2.html usinq two lists holding the images (left & right) and a main container. If the user hits the right stack the main image floats to the left and the new one is brought on top and vice versa.

Now I was controlling all the work through Firefox and it works perfectly there. my issue starts with Chrome where it performs with images flying all over the place and especially IE. no image shows up.

I know one problem could be that i'm using fixed and absolute positioning of information and so when animating i'm getting the proper coordinates to offset().

Any help is much apprecieated :)?

Comment: In IE I know that just setting the z-index of an element that's far down the DOM tree doesn't necessarily put it on top. That's because for some reason IE values the original order of elements. When I was working with some slideshows I actually moved the elements in the DOM to be safe, and explicitly set the z-index of anything involved in the animations. I believe Google can help you with that. For Chrome I suspect it's an offset/position issue. Try to output all offsets and positions and see what happens.

Comment: IE though is givng me : invalid argument in the jquery library, so i'm not sure it's the z-index problem

Comment: I've also checked Chrome: practically the values are correct but the difference it seems that in Chrome an absolute positioned element position is not based on the relative position parent as in FF. at least for the .css() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that i was applying javascript .css in pixels whilst the .animate in percentages. once both of them where in px it worked fine for all :)